# google map marker with transparent text label

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How to put marker on Google map with transparent text label ?

Example: 
Google Map with weather overlays has temperature with transparent background.
The label for the marker dynamically changes. Ex As temp changes the label changes too.

[image: Google map with weather option selected]

Comment: are you sure its text and not an image? Also, http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @gorelative Not 100% sure, but then it may be transparent image.The background of 75F in one place matches with the background.If you see the place names that too matches with the background. I want 2 provide a transparent label for my markers which would frequently be changing like temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/) utility library. Here's [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/181/)

The minimum requirement is a CSS style.

```
.labels {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  border: 0;
}
```

​

```
  var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,-5),
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "Tina's transparent Marker With Label",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
  });
```

Comment: Links out of date.

Comment: References a library, but link to library doesn't work (6 years later). As such, this answer is no longer valid. -1

Answer (score 2):

Please, do not use a library if you just need to change label opacity.

You can use:

```
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: {
        text: 'Hello World!',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    }
})
```